# remote channel message: Unreasonable to_self_delay = 2016 (max=2000)

Tags: lightning-network

so tried to open a node whose owner opened the port but I get this message above: remote channel message: Unreasonable to_self_delay = 2016 (max=2000). I tried on both elcair wallet and bitcoin lightning wallet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you can configure the timelock that you wish your channels should have and the maximum timelock that you are willing to accept. Eclair mobile will set the maximum value that is allowed according to the protocol which is 2016 blocks or statistically two weeks. This means you can technically have your mobile turned off for up to two weeks and still be able to act upon a channel breach.

It looks though like the other node you have has set that it will not accept values above 2000.

You should see if you can configure one or both nodes to make those values be compatible to each other

Comment: Thank you! I was able to increase the maximum amount on the remote node! :D Much love from a fellow crypto dude. If you have a node, a channel or even a bitcoin address, please let me know! SOOO EXCITED!

Comment: You can find all of that at https://voting.ln.rene-pickhardt.de including a link to my yt channel where I explain more about the lightning Network. Thanks for your interest in this technology and asking questions at the right place (: